# How to unstack the Period column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I was wondering how I could unstack each year separately into its own column from the dentist.csv file found here https://www.kaggle.com/utkarshxy/who-worldhealth-statistics-2020-complete?select=safelySanitization.csv

[image: Dataframe display]

Thanks

Comment: Try to read through this documentation. Pivot is the right approach. The examples in the link [Reshaping and pivot tables](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/reshaping.html) should help you

Answer (score 0):

Use df=dent.groupby("period") To group the data and then apply df.unstack(level=-1) to unstack